# Get selectedvalue of multiple parameter selections

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have written a DAX code which gets the `SELECTEDVALUE` based on what the user has selected from a parameter slicer, however, this only works for one single selection. How would I go about getting a concatenation of the multiple slicer selections from the parameter slicer?

```
selectedMetric = 
VAR __SelectedValue =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'TotalShareMetrics', TotalShareMetrics[Parameter Fields], TotalShareMetrics[Parameter]),
        TotalShareMetrics[Parameter]
    )

RETURN __SelectedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

Create a calculated column which will be a text field of the parameter names.

This column can then be used in the CONCATENATEX function when multiple selections have been made

```
selectedMetric = 
VAR __SelectedValue =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'TotalShareMetrics', TotalShareMetrics[Parameter Fields], TotalShareMetrics[Parameter]),
        TotalShareMetrics[Parameter]
    )

RETURN CONCATENATEX(VALUES(TotalShareMetrics[parameterName]), TotalShareMetrics[parameterName], ", ")
```